# Generate column not considering specific value in string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Hello this seems rather easy but has proven to beat my current knowledge. I'm working with a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['Mark','John','Tom','Silver'],'id':['501-8','627-5','523-3','632-2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

             Name     id
0            Mark  501-8
1            John  627-5
2             Tom  523-3
3          Silver  632-2
```

All I want, is to create an extra column `new_id` that contains the value of id without the `-`:

```
             Name     id   new_id
0            Mark  501-8     5018
1            John  627-5     6275
2             Tom  523-3     5233
3          Silver  632-2     6322
```

I've tried the following (Attempt 1):

```
df['new_id'] = df['id'].map({'-':''})
```

Returns:

```
             Name     id   new_id
0            Mark  501-8      NaN
1            John  627-5      NaN
2             Tom  523-3      NaN
3          Silver  632-2      NaN
```

Attempt 2:

```
df['new_id'] = df['id'].replace(to_replace={'-':''})
```

Returns:

```
             Name     id   new_id
0            Mark  501-8    501-8
1            John  627-5    627-5
2             Tom  523-3    523-3
3          Silver  632-2    632-2
```

Attempt 3:

```
df['new_id'] = df['id'].str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Returns:

```
             Name     id   new_id
0            Mark  501-8      501
1            John  627-5      627
2             Tom  523-3      523
3          Silver  632-2      632
```

And I'm pretty much out of ideas. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `df['new_id'] = df['id'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')`

Comment: `final=df.assign(new_id=df['id'].str.replace('-','').astype(int))` or `df['id'].str.findall('(\d+)').str.join('').astype(int)` <- with findall

Comment: `df['id'].replace('-','', regex=True)`

Comment: All three work, thanks a lot. Feel free to provide answers I'll upvote. @QuangHoang why is your replace working and mine not? Is it because of the `regex=True`?

Comment: @CeliusStingher Yes, `replace` without `regex=True` looks at the whole value/string, i.e. if your data is `'-'`, then it turns to `''`.

Comment: Ah, I was close then, will have that in mind for the next time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 3 comments with 3 different solutions. Let me join with another :)  `df.id.str.translate(str.maketrans('','','-'))`

Comment: `translate` was not part of my toolbox, thanks for the valuable comment!!

Comment: `str.translate` is a method from `str` accessor of pandas the same as `str.replace`. `str.maketrans` is the built-in  class function of string class of python.

Comment: This works, too: df["new_id"]= df.id.str.split("-").str.join('')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['new_id'] = (df.id.str.extract(r'(\d+)-(\d+)')[0] + df.id.str.extract(r'(\d+)-(\d+)')[1]).astype(int)

     Name     id  new_id
0    Mark  501-8    5018
1    John  627-5    6275
2     Tom  523-3    5233
3  Silver  632-2    6322
```

or simpler:

```
df['new_id']  = df.id.replace(r'(\d+)\-(\d+)', r'\1\2', regex=True)

     Name     id new_id
0    Mark  501-8   5018
1    John  627-5   6275
2     Tom  523-3   5233
3  Silver  632-2   6322
```